# How to follow redirects inside test cases?

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, spec2

Based on: [Testing a page that is loaded after a redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263971/testing-a-page-that-is-loaded-after-a-redirect)

Play!2.0 Framework (Scala) does have API which we can use to make redirects. However is there any way in Play Framework ( Scala ) that the test case automatically follows redirect responses. I would not want to repeat the redirect logic every time.

How to follow redirects inside test cases for Play Framework ( Scala ) ?

Comment: Is this for an integration test? If not, why would you need to access the other page? There are other ways to test redirect urls and flash data, etc..

Comment: I am using spec2 in a Play application. Essentially I am testing a route on homepage `/`, which redirect to `login/`. What are other ways to test redirect urls, flash data etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: To make it completely clear. There isn't a built-in way to do this, and for a good reason. Unit tests are supposed to be simple and isolated. A single unit test is meant to test a single piece of functionality.

*Example*: You make a `GET` request to a page that needs authentication, but you provide no credentials, so the server responds with `SEE OTHER` and a flash message attached. You then make sure it responded to that request appropriately. Test over. The controller function that responds with `SEE OTHER` should have no knowledge of the other, other than *maybe* it'll do something with that flash data.

*Example 2*: You make a `GET` request to a login page with flash data attached. The server responds with `OK` and an HTML view displaying the flash message within it. You make sure it does so.

If you really want to tie these two together, then perhaps tests using [WithBrowser](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithSpecs2) would suit you more.

---

If you're testing redirect information, it's better to isolate it from whatever controller function/view the redirect is pointing to. There are test helpers you can use to achieve this.

Let's say you want to test

```
Redirect("/login").flashing("message" -> "You are not logged in.")
```

In your test you could use these helpers:

```
import play.api.test._

val request = FakeRequest(GET, "/secretpage")
val Some(result) = route(request)
status(result) must equalTo(SEE_OTHER)
redirectLocation(result) must beSome("/login")
flash(result).get("message") must beSome("You are not logged in.")
```

Note that this is for Play 2.1.x and above. If you're using 2.0.x, you should change `route` to `routeAndCall`.

Comment: My question is if Play supports any mechanism to automatically follow redirects. I am already using `redirectLocation` method right now.

Comment: Not in unit tests. You make a request and get a result, and should really only test that result. If you want to test the function that's been redirected to, you should do that separately.